# ajax in wordpress with jquery

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to use ajax in wordpress.

I don't get ajax response. If I have done mistake on code, please let me know.

Here is my jquery code

```
// ajax submitting for the name
    $("#sendemp").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var submit_val = $("#searchbox").val();
    alert('submitval is ' + submit_val);
    $.ajax( {
        type : "POST",

        url : "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data : {
            action : 'deatils_search',
            user_name : submit_val
        },
        success : function(data) {
                alert('hhh');
            $('#accordion3').html(data);
            // $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
            // source: data
            // });

        }
    });

});
```

Here is my php code

```
function deatils_search() {


    $name=$_POST['user_name'];//retrive data from post array on form submitting
$jason  =$name;

    echo json_encode($jason) ;

    //echo '</div>';
    //wp_reset_query();
    die();
} // end theme_custom_handler
add_action( 'wp_ajax_deatils_search', 'deatils_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_deatils_search', 'deatils_search');
```

I tried to print alert('hhh'); on success message in ajax call. But it doesn't print anything.
Where I have done the mistake?

Please check bellow network tab on chrome
[image]

Comment: and what your console says ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' but it come from gd-bbpress

Comment: Though I use `   e.preventDefault();` page is refreshed when I click the submit button.

Comment: Check the network tab on Chrome Dev Tools, you can analyze xhr requests there

Comment: you can try to add .done() and see what response code it returned or just as @koala_dev said check net tab in firebug or other debugging tool you're using.

Comment: this time I saw lot of 304 status code

Comment: Open the network tab, click XHR and then submit your form, you should see a new entry with the ajax request

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$` as a jQuery shortcut within WordPress javascript. WordPress is set to run jQuery in noConflict mode. Replace `$` with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

When I replace the following method with click method., Every thing started to work.

```
$("#sendemp").click(function(e) {
```